# Associating Filename with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to provide a solution that allows a file upload to a REST API with a C# back-end. Currently I am able to upload the files and obtain the progress of their uploads using XMLHttpRequests and JavaScript. The issue I am having is that all of the files upload concurrently and I see mixed console messages with the upload progress.

My question is as follows: **Is there a way for me to associate the filename or file information passed in from the form so that I can figure out which file's progress I am currently looking at?**

Looking at the `e` variable within the `onprogress` I wasn't able to find any identifiers for the file except for the sizes of the files which makes sense if the upload is considered to be its own entity.

My code is below with the console log attempt for three files:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="button" id="uploadButton" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#uploadButton').click(function () {

var files = document.forms['uploadForm']['files[]'].files; //Gather files from the form
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { //for each file
    console.log(files[i].name + "; " + files[i].type + "; " + files[i].size); //log file info
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append(files[i].name, files[i]); //create a new form and push the file into it

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create a new request
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) { //tell xmlhttprequest what to do on upload progress update
        var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total; //onprogress function logs to console the proper percentage
        console.log('xhr.upload progress: ' + done + ' / ' + total + ' = ' + (Math.floor(done / total * 1000) / 10) + '%');
    };
    xhr.open("post", "/api/contact", true); //open request
    xhr.send(form); // send form

}

});
```

**CONSOLE FROM THREE FILE ATTEMPT**

```
Index:91 1184x1600.png; image/png; 1467392
Index:91 Example.pdf; application/pdf; 65391
Index:91 FileZilla_3.27.0.1_win64-setup.exe; application/x-msdownload; 7873888
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 65588 / 65588 = 100%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 65536 / 1467587 = 4.4%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 32768 / 7874140 = 0.4%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 1294336 / 1467587 = 88.1%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 1425408 / 7874140 = 18.1%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 1467587 / 1467587 = 100%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 3915776 / 7874140 = 49.7%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 6127616 / 7874140 = 77.8%
Index:98 xhr.upload progress: 7874140 / 7874140 = 100%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object that contains information about the file, you can attach that object to xhr (`xhr.fileInfo = {filename: "" + files[i].name}`), and that object should be available during your event handling.

Comment: Is there a reason that this would become persistent through the loop cycles, resulting in all messages showing progress but only with the last file's filename? I swear this worked yesterday and now it is only showing the last file's name...

Comment: If you don't declare the variable as local to the block, you could end up with a global that keeps getting overwritten.  It might not be the filename in the object - it might be a temporary variable used as part of the display/log process.

Comment: When you say "declare the variable as local to the block" do you mean creating a name variable within the ```onprogress``` method? Or do you mean I should create a name variable within the upload function?